# Is it possible to read local video file from Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, file, firefox, firefox-addon

I have need to open and automatically play video file that resides on client's computer from web page loaded inside Firefox. I hope this would be possible by developing Firefox extension.

Is it possible to access local video file inside Firefox extension using absolute file path? If yes - how? Is there any documentation / information available?

(If this is not correct place to ask, where can i ask this question?)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research, based on all information I have gathered, the answer is no: You can not automatically, from webpage using javascript, access local video file on clients computer even using Firefox extensions.

(If somebody has different information, It would be great if you shared it with us.)